# Dynamic embedded resource path in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin app in which I would like to use an embedded resource in my shared App project using a custom view that looks like this:

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"

...

<views:Icon ResourceId="{Binding IconPath}" 
    WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

The binding `IconPath` contains a string: `MyApp.Images.dashboard.approach.svg`.

This path is not valid though and my app cannot find it. When printing the embedded resources I get the following:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
foreach (var res in assembly.GetManifestResourceNames())
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found resource: " + res);
}

> found resource: MyApp.UWP.App.xaml
> found resource: MyApp.UWP.MainPage.xaml
> found resource: MyApp.UWP.Images.dashboard.approach.svg
```

So it seems `UWP`, `[target platform]`, is being added to the path. When using this "full" path, the icon is rendered.

Is there anyway I can avoid this extra prefix in this project with shared code? If not, is there an API I can use in my view model to add the `[target platform]`-prefix to my `IconPath` dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a custom `LogicalName` to override the Namespace/assembly generated one.

Either via the `Property` panel for the item in Visual Studio or via the `.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="my.svg">
      <LogicalName>MyCustomSVGName.svg</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```

In this case it will be:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Images\dashboard\approach.svg">
  <LogicalName>MyApp.Images.dashboard.approach.svg</LogicalName>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure how to use this. I can't see any `LogicalName` in my properties panel on VS 2017 Community and how are include path and logical name paths defined in more detail?

Comment: @span Edit the `.csproj` directly (It is also called a `Resource ID` in the VS4M IDE)

Comment: Thanks, added an edit if any more noobs like me come along. I didn't have a `csproj` but rather a `shproj` file. I could add to `projitems` file instead :)

Comment: @span Thanks for edit, did not think about you using a shared project...

Comment: This is an elegant solution. However it is extremely cumbersome for a situation with many images, and also requires hard-coding the image paths, which doesn't satisfy the original request for a dynamic resource path.